# Google chart animates in react without any interaction with graph data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, charts, react-google-charts

I am using Google chart (react-google-charts) in react to create a stacked bar graph, and i am using animation to show data, but something very unexpected happened, some of the bars starts animating without any interaction with the graph data or graph. when i click on any other component it animates or if the browser window slightly moves it animates.

Please check the attached video, if any of the community members can help, please do.

https://streamable.com/id68jb

Thanks in advance.